# Why does Wolfram say that $\dfrac{d}{dz}(\frac{i}{2}\operatorname{Log}\left(\frac{z+i}{z-i}\right))=\frac{1}{1+z^2}$, and is it true?

Tags: complex-analysis

Is [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=D%5BDivide%5Bi%2C2%5DLog%20%5C%2840%29Divide%5Bz%2Bi%2Cz-i%5D%20%5C%2841%29%2Cz%5D) wrong in claiming that $\dfrac{d}{dz}(\frac{i}{2}\operatorname{Log}\left(\frac{z+i}{z-i}\right))=\frac{1}{1+z^2}$?

One way of arriving at the above being true is by doing the following:

Let $\operatorname{Log}$ denote the multi-valued natural log defined over the nonzero complex numbers.

$$\int \frac{dz}{1+z^2}=\int \frac{\frac{i}{2}}{z+i}-\frac{\frac{i}{2}}{z-i}dz=\frac{i}{2}\operatorname{Log}\left(\frac{z+i}{z-i}\right)$$

Comment: Have you tried taking the derivative of $(i/2)\log((z+i)/(z-i))$ to see whether you get $(1+z^2)^{-1}$? If you do, then Wolfram says it's true because it's true.

Comment: @GerryMyerson if it's true then does it mean that\begin{align*}\arctan\left(z_2\right)-\arctan\left(z_1\right)&=\int_{z_{1}}^{z_{2}}\frac{dz}{z^{2}+1}=\int_{z_{1}}^{z_{2}}\frac{\frac{i}{2}}{z+i}-\frac{\frac{i}{2}}{z-i}dz\\&=\frac{i}{2}\operatorname{Log}\left(\frac{z_{2}+i}{z_{2}-i}\right)-\frac{i}{2}\operatorname{Log}\left(\frac{z_{1}+i}{z_{1}-i}\right)\end{align*}? If not, why not?

Comment: Have you checked to see whether that string of equations holds? Do you have a reason to doubt it? You may have to take care when choosing branches....

Comment: @GerryMyerson yes I checked with Wolfram. Wolfram says they do not hold. And that is my reason to doubt it. There seems to be a contradiction, if I'm understanding correctly https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=arctan%5C%2840%29-r%5C%2841%29-arctan%5C%2840%29r%5C%2841%29-%5C%2840%29Divide%5Bi%2C2%5D%5C%2841%29%5C%2840%29ln%5C%2840%29%5C%2840%29Divide%5B-r%2Bi%2C-r-i%5D%5C%2841%29-ln%5C%2840%29Divide%5Br%2Bi%2Cr-i%5D%5C%2841%29%5C%2841%29%5C%2841%29

Comment: @GerryMyerson what I think is going on is that Wolfram is being very uncareful with it's usage of log. I can change Log to ln and Wolfram will still insist that $∫\frac{dz}{1+z^2}=\frac{i}{2}\ln(\frac{z+i}{z-i})$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that if $x$ is real, then $x-i$ and $x+i$ have the same magnitude and the angle from $x-i$ to $x+i$ is $2\arctan (1/x)$. Thus, indeed,
$$\frac i2\log\left(\frac{x+i}{x-i}\right) = \frac i2(2i\arctan (1/x))=-\arctan (1/x)=\arctan x-\frac\pi 2.$$

Answer (score 1):

Let's calculate together:

$$D \log \frac{z+i}{z-i} = D \left( \log(z+i) - \log(z-i)\right)$$

Since $\log a/b = \log a - \log b, b \neq 0$. So,

$$D \log \frac{z+i}{z-i} = \frac1{z+i} - \frac1{z-i} = -\frac{-2i}{z^2+1}$$

Multiplying both sides by $i/2$ gives the result you were asking for. So yes, it's true!

Comment: the rule that $\log(\frac{x}{y})=\log(x)-\log(y)$ which is true for nonzero real numbers is in general not true for nonzero complex numbers. So isn't it actually inappropriate to use the log division rule as you did?

Comment: @SimonM, the "rule of logarithms" is only off by possible constants that are integer multiples of $2\pi i$, which are annihilated by the derivative...

Comment: @paulgarrett annihilated is a fun way to put it lol I think I will use that from now on xd